# Remove duplicate keys with same name and value from different arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following 8 associative arrays from an API which include a key named "platform" that has either 5 or 21 as value.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [category] => 0 [platform] => 5 [date] => 1163894400000 [region] => 2 [human] => 2006-Nov-19 [y] => 2006 [m] => 11 ) [1] => Array ( [category] => 0 [platform] => 5 [date] => 1165017600000 [region] => 5 [human] => 2006-Dec-02 [y] => 2006 [m] => 12 ) [2] => Array ( [category] => 0 [platform] => 5 [date] => 1165449600000 [region] => 3 [human] => 2006-Dec-07 [y] => 2006 [m] => 12 ) [3] => Array ( [category] => 0 [platform] => 5 [date] => 1165536000000 [region] => 1 [human] => 2006-Dec-08 [y] => 2006 [m] => 12 ) [4] => Array ( [category] => 0 [platform] => 21 [date] => 1165017600000 [region] => 5 [human] => 2006-Dec-02 [y] => 2006 [m] => 12 ) [5] => Array ( [category] => 0 [platform] => 21 [date] => 1165795200000 [region] => 2 [human] => 2006-Dec-11 [y] => 2006 [m] => 12 ) [6] => Array ( [category] => 0 [platform] => 21 [date] => 1166140800000 [region] => 1 [human] => 2006-Dec-15 [y] => 2006 [m] => 12 ) [7] => Array ( [category] => 0 [platform] => 21 [date] => 1166486400000 [region] => 3 [human] => 2006-Dec-19 [y] => 2006 [m] => 12 ) )
```

In my script, I am using a foreach loop to display on my website the actual platform and not the platform id (in this case "Wii" and "GameCube" instead of 5 and 21). However, since the key "platform" is included 8 times (4 times with "5" as value and 4 times with "21") I have duplicates when I do an echo. See below:

My code:

```
foreach($game_platform_arrays as $key => $innerArray){
    foreach($innerArray as $innerKey => $game_platform){
        if ($innerKey == "platform" and $game_platform == "5"){
            $game_platform = "Wii";
            echo $game_platform;
        }
        if ($innerKey  == "platform" and $game_platform == "21"){
            $game_platform = "Nintendo GameCube";
            echo $game_platform;
        }
    }
}
```

My output:

```
WiiWiiWiiWiiNintendo GameCubeNintendo GameCubeNintendo GameCubeNintendo GameCube
```

I don't know what to do to remove the duplicates from the output. My best guess would be to remove from the arrays the duplicate keys that have the same name and value but I am not sure how to proceed. If someone could point me in the right direction, this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: take a look at `array_unique` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @Adrien, how about you google the title, before submitting a question

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Thanks! I already took a look and this doesn't work when duplicates are from different arrays.

Comment: @tereško how about you don't assume that I didn't do my homework, before posting a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example for how you can do this:

```
<?php
$game_platform_arrays = [
0 => [
    'platform' => 5,
    ],
1 => [
    'platform' => 5
],
2 => [
    'platform' => 21
    ],
3 => [
    'platform' => 21
    ]
];
$name = '';
foreach($game_platform_arrays as $key => $innerArray){
   foreach($innerArray as $innerKey => $game_platform){
    if ($innerKey == 'platform' && $game_platform == '5' && $name != 'Wii'){
        echo $name = 'Wii';
    }
    if ($innerKey  == 'platform' && $game_platform == '21' && $name != 'Nintendo GameCube'){
        echo $name = 'Nintendo GameCube';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't think this will work for me because the arrays are created based on the json data from the API so the platforms will change every time I do a request. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: In your question you said it will either be 5 or 21 - the same as your code says. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Just note that it doesn't work if the game platform doesn't come grouped together.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll keep an eye out for that.

Comment: You can fix that potential problem by adding the name variable to an array, check for its existance, and if it's there, skip it. `if (in_array())`-basically.